# can't click close tage when use CSS3 lightbox

Tags: css, lightbox

I try to learn write a pure CSS lightbox, but when I click the button, I can't click the close tag, the position will return top:0 / left:0.

here is my [code sample](http://codepen.io/mukiwu/full/sbwmf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
a:hover{
    /* Remove positin:relative.  Line no: 39  */

}
```

The close button will align to left of the box, you've to make align to right if you want to